# Put Method Writning in Map Class?

Tags: java, methods, maps

I am coding the `MapClass` right now, but I can't seem to figure out the `put` method. This is what I have so far:

```
public V put(K key, V value)
{
    for(MapEnt<K,V> x:data)
    {
        if(x.getKey().equals(key))
        {
            V reval = x.getValue();
            x.setValue(value);
            return reval;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm having trouble with what to put in the else to add an entry. I have an `ArrayList` of keys and values.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Nothing** (i.e. remove the `else` part). You don't want to do anything there in case a entry with a appropriate key is found later in the list.

**After** the loop you need to add a new entry, since you know there is no entry with an appropriate key in the entry list.

BTW: If you want to allow the key to be `null`, use `Objects.equals` to check equality instead of calling `equals` (which may yield a `NullPointerException`)

Comment: Thanks! but when I format it as 'data.add(key,value)' it won't compile. Do you know why?

Comment: @IsabellaF: there is no method with a appropriate signature in `ArrayList`. Use something like this: `data.add(new MapEnt(key, value));` (assuming such a constructor exists in `MapEnt`), i.e. add a `MapEnt` object to the list.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this (the details depend on the type of map you're implementing). However this might be what you're asking for.

```
// Returns matching value or null if no value exists for this key.
public V put( K key, V value )
{
    V existingValue = null;

    // The downside of this for each loop is that it will iterate through all
    // entries, even if a match is found part way through.
    for ( MapEnt<K, V> x : data )
    {
        if ( x.getKey().equals( key ) )
        {
            // Match found.
            existingValue = x.getValue();
            x.setValue( value );
        }
    }

    if ( existingValue == null )
    {
        // No match was found. add new entry (exactly where you add it will
        // Depend on the type of map you are implementing.
    }

    return existingValue;
 }
```